# I can't filter the taxonomies connected to a content, it gives me only one result and all the rest remain invisible

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I installed a version of drupal 9 on a new hosting, and I started from scratch.
It gives me a visualization problem for the taxonomy
I created a Movie News content in which I inserted the taxonomy terms with the names of actors that I called Movie Actor, and I created a new content to create the actors page with the terms Movie Actor with the various names of the actors attached.
Each actor page has an image and taxonomy that identifies it with the actor's name.
On the Movie News page I added in the compilation of the page the taxonomies of the actors to make sure that by creating a views it can recognize the actors who must be displayed for that page and I inserted the views with the list of actors in the movie news page to be able to filter them correctly, each movie news page has its actors.
The only problem is that every time I enter the views of Movie Actor so that I can view the list of actors in the movie news content, it only shows the first actor that is inserted into the movie news page, and all the rest are not displayed, and I can't understand why.
I created the Views Movie Actor setting it perfectly with a Contextual filters - Content: Has taxonomy term ID filter to be able to display the right actors with that views on the movie news page but it doesn't work. Only 1 actor is displayed that matches the first actor entered on the movie News content creation page, excluding all others.
If you can help me I would be grateful.
Do you have any ideas???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is aggregation enabled?

Comment: no, I don't have aggregation enabled

Comment: Did you enable Multiple values on your Contextual filter? You need to share your Contextual filter settings, preferably in a good screenshot.